# How to resolve circular dependencies in VS Lightswitch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have an entity in Table A that is referenced by multiple children from Table B but Table A also references a main child from Table B. How do I delete an entity from Table A? The exception given is Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Comment: can't edit the tables, my task is to just create an admin tool for it. Is there a way to control the ordering of deletion in lightswitch, tried editing the deleting and deleted functions in datasource code but it seems lightswitch tries to delete them all at the same time

Answer (score 1):

This is a design issue, your database design should be normalized. After normalizing your problem should be fixed.

If normalizing does not solve your problem, could you give a real world example to give us a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I can't edit the datasource. I could just set the main child to null in the function entity_deleting(Entity entity) but I cant control the ordering of how lightswitch saves to the database, lightswitch doesn't allow calls to savechanges() inside deleting and deleted functions.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a design issue but you could do it programatically yourself.  Within a transaction you could first delete the relevant entries in Table B and then do the main deletion in Table A.

HTH